# Linux AIO: Poor Scaling

Tags: c++, linux, unix, ext4, aio

I am writing a library that uses the Linux asynchronous I/O system calls, and would like to know why the `io_submit` function is exhibiting poor scaling on the ext4 file system. If possible, what can I do to get `io_submit` not to block for large IO request sizes? I already do the following (as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/kernel/wiki/AIOUserGuide)):

- Use `O_DIRECT`.
- Align the IO buffer to a 512-byte boundary.
- Set the buffer size to a multiple of the page size.

In order to observe how long the kernel spends in `io_submit`, I ran a test in which I created a 1 Gb test file using `dd` and `/dev/urandom`, and repeatedly dropped the system cache (`sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`) and read increasingly larger portions of the file. At each iteration, I printed the time taken by `io_submit` and the time spent waiting for the read request to finish. I ran the following experiment on an x86-64 system running Arch Linux, with kernel version 3.11. The machine has an SSD and a Core i7 CPU. The first graph plots the number of pages read against the time spent waiting for `io_submit` to finish. The second graph displays the time spent waiting for the read request to finish. The times are measured in seconds.

[image]

[image]

For comparison, I created a similar test that uses synchronous IO by means of `pread`. Here are the results:

[image]

It seems that the asynchronous IO works as expected up to request sizes of around 20,000 pages. After that, `io_submit` blocks. These observations lead to the following questions:

- Why isn't the execution time of `io_submit` constant?
- What is causing this poor scaling behavior?
- Do I need to split up all read requests on ext4 file systems into multiple requests, each of size less than 20,000 pages?
- Where does this "magic" value of 20,000 come from? If I run my program on another Linux system, how can I determine the largest IO request size to use without experiencing poor scaling behavior?

The code used to test the asynchronous IO follows below. I can add other source listings if you think they are relevant, but I tried to post only the details that I thought might be relevant.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
// For `__NR_*` system call definitions.
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/aio_abi.h>

static int
io_setup(unsigned n, aio_context_t* c)
{
    return syscall(__NR_io_setup, n, c);
}

static int
io_destroy(aio_context_t c)
{
    return syscall(__NR_io_destroy, c);
}

static int
io_submit(aio_context_t c, long n, iocb** b)
{
    return syscall(__NR_io_submit, c, n, b);
}

static int
io_getevents(aio_context_t c, long min, long max, io_event* e, timespec* t)
{
    return syscall(__NR_io_getevents, c, min, max, e, t);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    const auto n = 4096 * size_t(std::atoi(argv[1]));

    // Initialize the file descriptor. If O_DIRECT is not used, the kernel
    // will block on `io_submit` until the job finishes, because non-direct
    // IO via the `aio` interface is not implemented (to my knowledge).
    auto fd = ::open("dat/test.dat", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT | O_NOATIME);
    if (fd < 0) {
        ::perror("Error opening file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char* p;
    auto r = ::posix_memalign((void**)&p, 512, n);
    if (r != 0) {
        std::cerr << "posix_memalign failed." << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto del = [](char* p) { std::free(p); };
    std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(del)> buf{p, del};

    // Initialize the IO context.
    aio_context_t c{0};
    r = io_setup(4, &c);
    if (r < 0) {
        ::perror("Error invoking io_setup");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Setup I/O control block.
    iocb b;
    std::memset(&b, 0, sizeof(b));
    b.aio_fildes = fd;
    b.aio_lio_opcode = IOCB_CMD_PREAD;

    // Command-specific options for `pread`.
    b.aio_buf = (uint64_t)buf.get();
    b.aio_offset = 0;
    b.aio_nbytes = n;
    iocb* bs[1] = {&b};

    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto r = io_submit(c, 1, bs);
    if (r != 1) {
        if (r == -1) {
            ::perror("Error invoking io_submit");
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Could not submit request." << std::endl;
        }
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto count = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1).count();
    // Print the wait time.
    std::cout << count << " ";

    io_event e[1];
    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    r = io_getevents(c, 1, 1, e, NULL);
    t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    count = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1).count();
    // Print the read time.
    std::cout << count << std::endl;

    r = io_destroy(c);
    if (r < 0) {
        ::perror("Error invoking io_destroy");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the same test with an older kernel version? For example 3.4? I'm saying just to be sure it's not due to a recent, yet-to-be-discovered bug in the kernel.

Comment: @Shahbaz No, not yet -- thanks for the suggestion. I'll do that and post again here.

Comment: I don't understand your graph. It looks like AIO after 20K pages *runs in constant time*, rather than blocks.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it seems that most of the IO is done in the `io_submit` function, which is what is blocking. By "time spent waiting for the read request to finish", I mean the time spent waiting for `io_getevents` to return. But since `io_submit` is scaling linearly w.r.t. the request size, it makes sense that `io_getevents` would return in constant time. Did I make a mistake in describing something?

Comment: Ah, I see. Your second graph is for just io_getevents. It's clear now.

Comment: @Shahbaz Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Linux machine with an older kernel version.

Comment: @void-pointer, it's not hard to compile your own. You can use the configuration of your current kernel so the configuration won't take time either.

Comment: Could `sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` be interfering with the program? Is it continuously running in parallel with the test program? Could you try doing the sync and write to file inside your program itself (to make it sequential, if not already of course)?

Comment: @Shahbaz Sure, I'll try that now. Compiling and installing the older kernel is going to take a little longer.

Comment: @Shahbaz I added the sync inside the program and removed it from the test script, but it did not make a difference.

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-size`?

Comment: @n.m. I spent a while looking around for this parameter, as according to many of the sources I visited, it is supposed to exist on my system. However, the file does not exist on my system, and `sysctl -a | grep aio` fails to bring up `aio-max-size`. Was this parameter deprecated? I'm trying to see if there is a default value.

Comment: @nm I found some relevant information [here](http://blog.abigold.fr/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=268:aio-max-nraio-nrasmlibaiofsaio-max-sizefsaio-max-nr-kiocbslabinfolibaio&catid=97:io&Itemid=57): "In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 2.1 and 3, the 2.4 series kernels offered a tuning parameter 'fs.aio-max-size' which when set to 1048576, would speed up and increase database performance. In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4 and 5, this option is no longer available..."

Comment: Just for fun you might look into `io_uring` which is a new type of AIO for Linux. It's only in the very newest kernels. I found https://kernel.dk/io_uring.pdf although not sure it is still up to date because it has been changing rapidly.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that very few (if any) filesystems on linux fully supports AIO. Some filesystem operations still block, and sometimes `io_submit()` will, indirectly via filesystem operations, invoke such blocking calls.

My understanding is further that the main users of kernel AIO primarily care about AIO being truly asynchronous on raw block devices (i.e. no filesystem). essentially database vendors.

[Here's](http://marc.info/?l=linux-aio&m=131812906107671&w=2) a relevant post from the linux-aio mailing list. ([head](http://marc.info/?l=linux-aio&m=131674474030215&w=2) of the thread)

A possibly useful recommendation:

> Add more requests via /sys/block/xxx/queue/nr_requests and the problem
>   will get better.

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't the execution time of io_submit constant?

Because you are submitting I/Os that are so big, the block layer has to split them up and then queue the resulting requests. This can then cause you to hit resource limitations that in turn cause `io_submit()` to behave as if it's blocking...

> What is causing this poor scaling behavior?

The bigger the I/O is over the splitting threshold (see below) the more likely it becomes that the number of splits done to turn it into appropriately sized requests will also increase (presumably actually doing the splits will cost a small amount of time too). With direct I/O `io_submit()` does not return until all its requests have been allocated and queued at the block layer level. Further, the amount of requests that can be queued by the block layer for a given disk is limited to `/sys/block/[disk_device]/queue/nr_requests`. Exceeding this limit leads to `io_submit()` blocking until enough request slots have been freed up such that all its allocations have been satisfied (this is related to [Arvid was recommending](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20984964/revisions)).

> Do I need to split up all read requests on ext4 file systems into multiple requests, each of size less than 20,000 pages?

Ideally you should split your requests into far smaller amounts than that - 20000 pages (assuming a 4096 byte page which is what is used on x86 platforms) is roughly 78 megabytes! This doesn't just apply to when you're using ext4 - doing such large `io_submit()` I/O sizes to other filesystems or even directly to block devices will be unlikely perform well.

If you work out which disk device your filesystem is on and look at `/sys/block/[disk_device]/queue/max_sectors_kb` that will give you an upper bound but the [bound at which splitting starts may be even smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59403297/2732969) so you may want to limit the size of each I/O to `/sys/block/[disk_device]/queue/max_segments * PAGE_SIZE` instead.

> Where does this "magic" value of 20,000 come from?

This is likely down to some combination of:

- The maximum size each I/O can be before the block layer splits it (at most this will be `/sys/block/[disk_device]/queue/max_sectors_kb` but the [observed split limit may be even lower](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533845/109111))
- The maximum number of I/Os that can be queued before blocking occurs (`/sys/block/[disk_device]/queue/nr_requests`)
- Your hardware's command queue depth (`/sys/block/[disk_device]/device/queue_depth`)
- How fast your disk is at completing requests. When the kernel can't queue any more I/Os to the real device (due to the hardware `queue_depth` being full and the kernel's additional queues being full) it **becomes blocking on new requests** until in-flight ones sent to the hardware have completed.

> If I run my program on another Linux system, how can I determine the largest IO request size to use without experiencing poor scaling behavior?

Limit each request I/O to the lower of `/sys/block/[disk_device]/queue/max_sectors_kb` or `/sys/block/[disk_device]/queue/max_segments * PAGE_SIZE`. I would imagine I/Os no bigger than 524288 bytes should be safe but your hardware may be able to cope with a larger size and thus get a higher throughput but possibly at the expense of completion (as opposed to submission) latency.

> If possible, what can I do to get io_submit not to block for large IO request sizes?

There's going to be an upper "good" limit and if you surpass it there are going to be consequences which you can't escape.

## Related questions

[asynchronous IO io_submit latency in Ubuntu Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34572559/2732969)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the purpose of using AIO in the first place.  The referenced example shows a sequence of [fill-buffer], [write], [write], [write], ... [read], [read], [read], ... operations. In effect you are stuffing data down a pipe.  Eventually the pipe fills up when you reach the I/O bandwidth limit to your storage.  Now you busy wait, which shows up on your linear performance degradation behavior.

The performance gains for an AIO write is that the application fills a buffer and then tells the kernel to begin the write operation; control returns to the application immediately while *the kernel still owns the data buffer and its content*; until the kernel signals I/O complete, the application must not touch the data buffer because you don't know yet what part (if any) of the buffer has actually made it to the media: modify the buffer before the I/O is complete and you've corrupted the data going out to the media.

Conversely, the gain from an AIO read is when the application allocates an I/O buffer, and then tells the kernel to begin filling the buffer.  Control returns to the application immediately and the application must *leave the buffer alone* until the kernel signifies it is finished with the buffer by posting the I/O completion event.

So the behavior you see is the example quickly filling a pipeline to the storage.  Eventually data are generated faster than the storage can suck in the data and performance drops to linearity while the pipeline gets refilled as quickly as it is emptied: linear behavior.

The example program *does* use AIO calls but it's still a linear stop-and-wait program.

Comment: The purpose of the busy wait in my program is to measure how long the kernel spends in the `io_submit` function vs the time spent between the submission of the IO request and the insertion of the request into the completion queue. I agree with you that the purpose of AIO is to allow the application to do other useful things while the kernel is filling the buffer. What my measurements show is that Linux AIO on ext4 is not suitable for this, because almost all of the time is spent in the `io_submit` function itself.

Comment: The referenced example also does not use any pipelining: only one  read operation is ever submitted. The writing/clearing the cache is done in an external script before running the program. The entire purpose of this exercise was simply to measure how long `io_submit` takes. Please let me know if you still think I have misunderstood what you were trying to tell me. As it stands I think that you misinterpreted what I was trying to show with my experiment.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer does not capture the OP's problem. Kernel AIO will cease to work asynchronously (if it runs asynchronously at all, it only does under very strict constraints anyway) under non-obvious conditions, such as queueing a few too many requests or queueing one that is too large. This is something I've experienced as well. The reason is (according to what I was told back then) a finite-size request queue and splitting up too large requests. In summary, kernel AIO simply doesn't work (in a sense of being asynchronous).

Comment: I don't think the original poster has misunderstood the purpose of aio. I think their testing methodology is sound.