# how does Linux get the max_hw_sectors_kb value?

Tags: linux, kernel, scsi

I'm trying to find how the Linux obtains the max_hw_sectors_kb value. I know that it comes from the HW itself but how?

Comment: Would depend on the type of storage and type of controller.  NVMe, SCSI and SATA would all be different.

Comment: It's a SCSI Device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux: writes are split into 512K chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494593/linux-writes-are-split-into-512k-chunks)

Comment: No, it doesn't. How does the SCSI tell the max_hw_sectors_kb value? is it calculated based on some device params or directly obtained using some commands?

Comment: See https://sg.danny.cz/sg/sg_io.html for some (old but nevertheless still valid) notes "how this works" on SCSI; the margin of an imprecise SO question is too small to hold a full explanation how device capability discovery and/or device attribute setting work in the implementation of the Linux SCSI subsystem (docs with impl reference: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/driver-api/scsi.rst).  Let's just say here "one can query the SCSI device itself for this information".